# Referencing attributes across multiple tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, rails-activerecord

Let me try and condense my question:

I want to display data from multiple tables in a particular view.  I want to list every person I have in a "People" table, and append there job on an "Affiliations" table listed with their company from an "Employers" table.  Affiliations should `belongs_to` People and Employers, and Employers and People `have_many` Affiliations. What would the migration and controller look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is the same as what you're asking, but using `has_many` and `belongs_to` may be a better solution. Using these associations would allow an employee to have many employers and then simply get the most recent one.

Please feel free to correct me if this isn't what you are asking.

Comment: Do I need to do anything besides declare them in the respective models?

Comment: the model with `belongs_to` needs a reference, created via migration. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, it may be of some help!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could just declare queries per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html after declaring "has_many" and "belongs_to" in the model and rake-ing.